# Bias of a Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, bias

Given a set of observations $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n), x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the maximum-likelihood Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ is given by $\mu = \bar{x}$ and $\Sigma = \widehat{\sigma}^2$, i.e., sample mean and sample variance.

If $X$ is not from a normal distribution, this estimate will never be accurate, no matter how much data I have. So my question is: What is the mean squared error? Or simpler: What is the bias and/or variance of the estimate?

Comment: If $X$ is not from a normal distribution, then exactly what do you suppose $\bar x$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ are estimating?

Comment: I guess the estimate is the Gaussian with minimal KL-divergence to the true generating distribution. The MSE/bias/variance could give a hint how wrong the Gaussian model assumption is.

Comment: Because that is an unusual meaning of "estimate," it would be well to define your terms within the question itself.

Comment: You can still estimate mean and variance for non-gaussian data and assuming the underlying distribution has a mean and variance, the sample estimates will converge to their true values as the data set increases in size.